# java.lang.IlleagalArgumentException: Plugin Already Initalized

Tags: java, minecraft

I am developing a plugin in Spigot 1.11.2 named CommandWizard. When I tried to load it on my test server, I got the following error:

```
Error occurred while enabling CommandWizard v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
    at 
org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:122) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.commandwizard.mc.gamemode.GameModeSpectator.<init>(GameModeSpectator.java:12) ~[?:?]
    at net.commandwizard.mc.Main.onEnable(Main.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:271) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:376) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:326) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:421) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:382) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:337) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:544) [spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:125) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.commandwizard.mc.Main.<init>(Main.java:9) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:301) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:204) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
    ... 2 more
```

I have gotten this error before, but cannot find anything online that fixes my problem. I only have 1 plugin on my test server which is this one.

Comment: Searching for `org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize` gives https://bukkit.org/threads/error-invalidpluginexception.458850/ - is that relevant to your situation?

Comment: Yes. I will add some changes to my code and if it works, I will mark this question as solved.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't fix the error, but at least it made me realize some other problems with my code that I fixed. So thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So...
The IllegalArgumentException gets thrown when you give an function a wrong argument.

This two lines

at net.commandwizard.mc.gamemode.GameModeSpectator.(GameModeSpectator.java:12)
at net.commandwizard.mc.Main.onEnable(Main.java:24)

say that there was an error in 12 in your GameModeSpectator-class.
This class was called in line 24 of your Main-class in the onEnable()- funxtion.

That means that you called an function in line 12 of the GameModeSpectator-class that caused that IllegalArgumentException. Maybe you can find out on your own what the mistake might be. If not you can post the code of the GameModeSpectator-class here and i´d be happy to help.

Comment: Lol, I actually forgot this existed a long time ago. I actually stopped working on it, but thanks anyway!